# Trying obfuscating Dot Net Core applications

Tags: .net-core, obfuscation

I am trying to obfuscate a Dot Net Core application but I am having no success. I am using ConfuserEx, managed to get it to work with a Net Framework, but no luck when trying it out with a Net Core Console Application or Net Core DLL.

I get the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Did anyone managed to obfuscate a Net Core application? If not is there any other tool that can do it?

Comment: Why downvotes? Isn't it a question related with programing?

Comment: Requests for tools are specifically off topic, from close reasons: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: I don't agree, I am allowed to ask about tools usefull for programing.

Comment: Hell, its even on the tour page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour
In the section Ask about... 4th point, programming tools.

Comment: You can ask about _using_ tools for programming, but asking to _find_ or _recommend_ tools is specifically off topic.  Read the middle part of [help/on-topic].

Comment: @jmoerdyk I disagree, This person is not asking for a tool. They are asking how you do something to .net based artifacts. I'm not entirely sure what the problem is either, but I am actually interested in an answer to this question.

Comment: Did you try to fire an issue here: https://github.com/yck1509/ConfuserEx ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [Obfuscar](https://www.obfuscar.com/). Its free and open source.

Binaries can be loaded at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Obfuscar/

Project sample:

```
<Obfuscator>
  <Var name="InPath" value=".\" />
  <Var name="OutPath" value=".\output" />

  <Var name="HideStrings" value="true" />
  <Var name="UseKoreanNames" value="true" />
  <Var name="ReuseNames" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameFields" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameProperties" value="true" />
  <Var name="RenameEvents" value="true" />
  <Var name="OptimizeMethods" value="true" />
  <Var name="SuppressIldasm" value="true" />
  <Var name="KeepPublicApi" value="false" />
  <Var name="HidePrivateApi" value="true" />  

  <Module file="$(InPath)\YourApplication.dll" />
</Obfuscator>
```

Running obfuscation:

```
  Obfuscar.Console.exe your_project.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw this error when I tried to obfuscate *EXE* file. *DLL*s do not yield this error.

But I need to add that at the moment ConfuserEx does not really support .NET Core assemblies, because it does not handle metapackages; all dependent assemblies must be explicitly specified in the main DLL, which makes it quite a hassle.